# What is the difference between declaring a global constant in a .cpp with .h extern declaration vs declaring the constant in the .cpp file?

Tags: c++

I have already found the solution to my problem, however, I do not understand why it was a problem to begin with and I thought I would ask here to better my understanding of things.

I have developed an application for an atmega micro in Atmel Studio 7. This project I have done in c++ written in a fairly c safe way only as an experiment. Previously embedded projects have been purely in C. Anyways I was writing unit tests for the application and I found that a test that had previously been passing was now failing. The situation:

there are 5 files of interest:

```
main.cpp  
constants.h  
UART.cpp  
UART.h  
UART_tests.h
```

in main.cpp I have declared a constant:
`const unsigned long SERIAL_NUMBER = 0x00123456;`
in constants.h I have this variable as an extern:
`extern const unsgigned long SERIAL_NUMBER`

In UART_tests.h I have a test like so:

```
ASSERT_EQUALS("\t\tHB", ((byte)(SERIAL_NUMBER >> 24)), mResponseBuffer[6])
ASSERT_EQUALS("\t\tMHB", ((byte)((SERIAL_NUMBER & 0x00FF0000) >> 16)), mResponseBuffer[7])
ASSERT_EQUALS("\t\tMLB", ((byte)((SERIAL_NUMBER & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)), mResponseBuffer[8])
ASSERT_EQUALS("\t\tLB", ((byte)(SERIAL_NUMBER & 0x000000FF)), mResponseBuffer[9])
```

ASSERT_EQUALS test looks like:

```
#define ASSERT_EQUALS(TEST, A, B) if(A != B){ \
                sprintf(buffer, equals, TEST, A, B); \
                UART_writeStringPolling(buffer); \
                test = false;}
```

with equals string as:
`const char equals[] = "%s expected %02d got %02d\r\n";`

mResponseBuffer is populated in the function I am testing the statements of interest are these:

```
case GET_SERIAL_NUMBER:
    buildResponse(SERIAL_NUMBER);
    sendResponse();  
    break; 

...  

bool buildResponse(const unsigned long b)
{
   byte b1, b2, b3, b4;

   b4 = (byte)b;
   b3 = (byte)(b >> 8);
   b2 = (byte)(b >> 16);
   b1 = (byte)(b >> 24);

   if(mResponseSize >= UART_BUFFER_SIZE-4)
      return false;

   mResponseBuffer[++mResponseSize] = b1;
   mResponseBuffer[++mResponseSize] = b2;
   mResponseBuffer[++mResponseSize] = b3;
   mResponseBuffer[++mResponseSize] = b4;

   return true;
}
```

So now with all of that setup complete the problem I had was that the value being placed in mResponseBuffer was not the actual value of SERIAL_NUMBER! In fact my debugger even reported the wrong value for SERIAL_NUMBER! So the test would fail and I would get a message like:

```
Testing GET_SERIAL_NUMBER:
    HB expected 00 got 03
    MHB expected 18 got 24
    MLB expected 52 got 00
    LB expected 86 got 05
    Test Failed
```

The expected values are correct! However even when this command is called the debugger shows the incorrect value for SERIAL_NUMBER. So it seems that the extern was being resolved not only incorrectly but differently depending on where in the code!

The solution was to take the declaration of SERIAL_NUMBER out of main.cpp and place it in constants.h. My question, finally, is why?

Comment: What type is mResponseBuffer?  If it's signed char array, this might be your issue.

Comment: Nope the declarations is: byte mResponseBuffer[UART_BUFFER_SIZE];

and byte is: typedef unsigned char byte;

Comment: Quick verification: did you include `constants.h` in `main.cpp`?

Comment: Why are you having global constants?

Comment: `constants.h` is included in `main.cpp`

Comment: I have global constants because there is not really a reason not to. The application is simple and single threaded. Also in embedded applications globals are often unavoidable as ISRs do not return results or accept arguments. I do, however, try to limit the use of globals when possible or when not possible I make them static and thus limiting their use to the specific file. In this case the constant SERIAL_NUMBER is used by many modules and so is made global for simplicity.

Comment: Not sure but I believe you are observing one of the subtle differences between C and C++. Global `const` integer. In C++ `const` means `static const` at the global scope which would mean that each translation units would get its own copy of `SERIAL_NUMBER`.

Comment: I believe you are correct. It is a wonder the compiler didn't give me an error or at least a warning that I was using an undefined variable.